# ip6tables with K26 std-nokaid-small firmware for my WNR2000 version 1 router?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, ipv6, ip6tables

I am looking at the K26 std-nokaid-small firmware for my WNR2000 (v1) router.

It is supposed to support IPv6, but is ip6tables (or other IPv6 compatible firewall) included in the image?

```
dd-wrt.v24-21061_NEWD-2_K2.6_std_nokaid_small.bin
```

Or can I install such modules independently?
Flash size is 4 MB and firmware takes 3.54 MB. IPv6 without firewall is pretty useless right?

Comment: I do not have the answer to your question, apart from assuming that it will most likely have ip6tables since this is the basis of security for all OSs. But I wish to suggest is that you mount dd-wrt onto a virtual machine (just google **dd-wrt virtualbox** or some such query for a guide). This way you will know for sure.

Comment: Ah cool suggestions! Thx!

Comment: Why use ancient DD-WRT when you can actually use modern firmware like OpenWrt?

Comment: So open wrt is better? I want ipv6 with firewall, and it has that, right?

Comment: Seems possible (though a bit complicated) to install: https://dev.openwrt.org/milestone/Backfire%2010.03.1

Comment: @JohnyTex Use the current version of OpenWrt, not two old versions back!

Comment: There were only instructions for that version, with v1 of the Router. I don't think I dare to experiment.